# Java String Characters in an Array

Tags: java, arrays, string, character

I have a problem in Java.
I want to putt all characters of an String into an Array with the exact amount of chars as in the String, so that all the letters of the word are present in an Array. Thanks for help :)

Comment: You can use [`String.toCharArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray--)

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`toCharArray`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray()) method in [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

```
String str = "asdf";
char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
```

Or just

```
char[] chars = "asdf".toCharArray();
```